# How to get navigation in SharePoint Online Document preview when linking directly to a file

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, preview

We're exploring using a SharePoint online document library to store a large set of PDFs and TIFs of engineering drawings.  There are probably 5,000 drawings. Our staff regularly reference these drawings, and really need to be able to easily navigate to the previous/next drawing.

The SPO preview navigation seems like the perfect fit.  They can use these navigation buttons.
[image: SPO navigation buttons, for paging forward and back between different files]

Here is the wrinkle: to help them find the initial drawing, we provide them a mapping interface (using an ESRI tool), and have a link to the file on the map.  In all of our testing, when we link directly to the file, the system doesn't see all the neighboring files, so the navigation is lost.

[image: After direct linking, the system doesn't see neighboring files, so there is no navigating between them]

Is there a way to format the direct link so that it "sees" the neighboring files, and allows the navigation?

Comment: Can you share more details like how you are generating using ESRI tool?

Comment: Hi Kalpesh, thanks for asking.  We haven't yet put the URL into the ESRI tool, because we haven't overcome this hurdle.  The additional detail you're probably looking for is this: if you go through the Sharepoint GUI to a document (where you can see the navigation to neighboring files), and copy the URL, then paste that exact same URL into a new browser window, the navigation will no longer be available.